# How to use `letrec` to define function "length" within the body of function "lengh-it"

Tags: function, recursion, scheme, letrec

```
(define length-it
  (lambda (ls)
    (length ls 0)))

(define length
  (lambda (ls acc)
    (if (null? ls)
        acc
        (length (cdr ls) (+ acc 1)))))
```

How to use `letrec` to put the function `length` within the body of function `length-it`?

The output should be `(length-it '(1 2 3))` -> `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with what we've got:

```
(define length-it 
   (lambda (ls) 
      (length ls 0)))
```

But actually, since there's also a built-in function called `length` too, let's rename ours to `my-length`:

```
(define my-length
  (lambda (ls acc)
    (if (null? ls)
        acc
        (my-length (cdr ls) (+ acc 1)))))
```

and now,

```
(define length-it 
   (lambda (ls) 
      (my-length ls 0)))
=
(define length-it 
   (let ((init 0))
     (lambda (ls) 
        (my-length ls 0))))       ;; (0)
=
(define length-it 
   (let ((init 0))                ;; (1)
     (lambda (ls) 
        (my-length ls init))))    ;; (2)
```

Does this work? To what entity does `init(2)` refer? Is it `init(1)`?

Next,

```
=
(define length-it 
   (let ((init 0)                                      ;; (0)
         (my-length                                    ;; (1)
            (lambda (ls acc) 
               (if (null? ls) 
                   acc 
                   (my-length (cdr ls) (+ acc 1))))))  ;; (2)
     (lambda (ls) 
        (my-length ls init))))                         ;; (3)
```

Now does *this* work? (be sure to test this in a new, fresh environment, *without* `my-length` being defined separately there at all).

No? Why not?

To what entity does the name `init(3)` refer? To what does `my-length(3)` refer?  To what does the name `my-length(2)` refer? Would it work if `my-length(2)` were referring to `my-length(1)` as does `my-length(3)`? Since it doesn't work, `my-length(2)` must refer to some other `my-length` defined above the `let` but do we have any more of them anywhere there?

So can you make it work? Were you supposed to use `let` there, or that other primitive, `letrec`? Are the two exactly the same? Probably not, otherwise why would they name the same thing twice? So can we try using the other one there? Would it perhaps make `my-length(2)` indeed refer to `my-length(1)` as it was supposed to do?

Does it work now?

Comment: and you say...? -- comments? feedback? anything?

Comment: If OP applies elbow grease and works through this, they might learn something. But, they may get confused when trying the final definition of `length-it` above; the inner `length` will be confused with the built-in `length` when errors are issued by the compiler. It might aid the clarity of error messages to change `length` to `my-length`.

Comment: @Will Ness: thank you so much for your detailed explanation. It works.

Comment: @user15225644 -- please consider [accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that you find useful. This signals to future visitors the the answer worked, rewards the answerer for taking the time to help (especially nice for a detailed answer such as this one), and gives you a small rep bump, too.